# Can we get applicaton wise uptime of each application in Newrelic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, newrelic-synthetics

Is it possible to get the application wise uptime for each application in Newrelic Dashboard.

```
SELECT percentage(count(*), WHERE result='SUCCESS' AND appName LIKE '%' AND  entity.guid='someid') FROM SyntheticCheck SINCE 5 week ago
```

Comment: yes it is possible, we are using same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this NRQL by using FACET monitorname. Also remove entity.guid unless you need it for something.

```
SELECT percentage(count(*), WHERE result='SUCCESS' AND appName LIKE '%') FROM SyntheticCheck SINCE 5 week ago FACET monitorname
```

Comment: what is monitor name here? How can I get it

Comment: Which product you are using of Newrelic. If it is Synthetics then monitor name is the synthetic monitor name which you have created. For APM and browser NRQL will change.

Comment: I executed the command in synthetics but I cant see anything, the dashboard is blank